# Как в phpstorm установить перенос строк по умолчанию?

Tags: phpstorm

Где в *phpstorm* устанавливается перенос строк по умолчанию?

Каждый раз при открытии проекта в каждом документе делать это отдельно очень напрягает.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-line-separators.html

Answer (score 24):

Отвечу уже не для автора, а для тех, кто гуглит этот вопрос. По умолчанию для всех файлов ставим так:

1. Идем в *File > Settings > Editor > General*. Ставим галочку `Use Soft wraps in Editor`
2. Если что-то все равно вылазит, то идем *File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > PHP*. Находим вкладку `Wrapping and Braces` и выставляем везде `Wrap if long`
3. Можно еще перейти на вкладку *Php doc* и поставить галочку на `Wrap long lines`. Я эффекта пока не прочувствовал, но вдруг.

Answer (score 10):

view - active editor - use soft wraps

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, нормальный ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl + Alt + S → Editor → Code Style → ...

Выбираете язык, и там можете настраивать любые отступы.

Answer (score 4):

Версия 2019.1. Сделал вот так:

[image: soft-wrap всегда и для всех файлов]

Answer (score 3):

В версии 2019.1.2 нужно зайти file > settings > editor > general в разделе Soft Wraps отметить галочку напротив Soft-wrap files и написать расширение того файла с которым работаете пример: *.md; *.txt; *.rst; *.adoc; *php; *html
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Зайди в Файл->Настройки->Редактор->Основные. Затем отметь пункт "Использовать переносы в редакторе" и все

Comment: Это вы о каком редакторе? Меню на русском??